# Lightning table going beyond borders

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I created a table in Aura Component, on getting data populated its going beyond borders.

Can anyone help me out in fixing this.
[image]

Aura Component:

```
<aura:component controller="DisplayDeviationApprovalView" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
            access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="Opportunities" type="Opportunity[]"  /> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="slds-p-top--medium slds-p-left--medium">
        <fieldset class="slds-form--compound custom-border">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.Opportunities}" var="opp" indexVar="key">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-clearfix">
                    <div class="slds-col_" style="width:150px;display:inline-block">
                        <div class="slds-has-divider--top" >
                            <b><ui:outputText aura:id="oppStage" value="{!opp.key}" /></b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="slds-table slds-border_left slds-border_right" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                                <th scope="col" width='150'>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Step Name">Step Name</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" width='150'>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">Date</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" width='75'>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" width='125'>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Assigned To">Assigned To</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" width='150'>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Comments">Comments</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <aura:iteration items="{!opp.value}" var="oppVal">
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-label="Step Name" width='150'>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Step_Name__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Date" width='150'>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.DateFormula__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Status" width='75'>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Status__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Assigned To" width='125'>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Assigned_To__r.Name}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Comments" width='150'>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Comments__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </aura:iteration>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

</aura:component>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `slds-table_fixed-layout` and `slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal` class to your `table` tag to use fixed layout for width and truncation purposes  and to creates stacked rows with horizontal cells.

Also, to make the column visible and not overlapping or hiding because of fixed layout you can use `slds-cell-wrap` class in your `th` and `td`.
And give the table's each cell a size rather than a fixed width (in your case I have given `slds-size_2-of-12`).

Column in each row should be marked as a `th` with a `scope="row"` attribute and the top row of column headers `(th)` are placed in a thead where each should receives the `scope="col"` attribute.

You can read more about slds data table [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/).

Below is your updated code:

```
<aura:component controller="DisplayDeviationApprovalView" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
            access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="Opportunities" type="Opportunity[]"  /> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="slds-p-top--medium slds-p-left--medium">
        <fieldset class="slds-form--compound custom-border">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.Opportunities}" var="opp" indexVar="key">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-clearfix">
                    <div class="slds-col_" style="width:150px;display:inline-block">
                        <div class="slds-has-divider--top" >
                            <b><ui:outputText aura:id="oppStage" value="{!opp.key}" /></b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="slds-table slds-border_left slds-border_right slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal slds-table_bordered" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps" scope="col">
                                <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Step Name">Step Name</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">Date</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Assigned To">Assigned To</div>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Comments">Comments</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <aura:iteration items="{!opp.value}" var="oppVal">
                                <tr scope="row" class="slds-hint-parent">
                                    <td data-label="Step Name" scope="row" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Step_Name__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Date" scope="row" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.DateFormula__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Status" scope="row" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Status__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Assigned To" scope="row" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Assigned_To__r.Name}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Comments" scope="row" class="slds-cell-wrap slds-size_2-of-12">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!oppVal.Comments__c}</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </aura:iteration>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Good a good answer, it is nice to emphasize the part of the solution rather than just posting the whole code as a answer.

Comment: Thanks will take care next time :))